# "Got a SIGABRT while executing native code." When I tap in an Entry

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I'm making an application in .Net MAUI that works fine on Android but when I pass it to IOS when I tap on Entry. This is the entry

```
<Frame Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
       VerticalOptions="Start" BorderColor="Gray" Padding="15,5" 
       CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
    <Entry  Placeholder="Usuario"  
            Text="{Binding Alias}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoadingGrid}" 
            FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#001f3f" PlaceholderColor="#AAAAAA" />
```

I get the following error:

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x1059bc1a0 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x10596c1c0 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x105c8ebc8 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : sigabrt_signal_handler.cold.1
    0x1059bba60 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_setup_stat_profiler
    0x103ab37e0 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x10457f124 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : pthread_kill
    0x1801655c0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
    0x1801e378c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib : malloc_vreport
    0x1801e3950 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib : malloc_report
    0x1801d78a0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib : find_zone_and_free
    0x181dd5fb0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Conten
ts/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu6Locale10setToBogusEv
    0x181dd7954 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu6LocaleaSERKS0_
    0x181f455f4 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu6number24LocalizedNumberFormatterC2EONS0_4impl10MacroPropsERKNS_6LocaleE
    0x181ef1494 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu13DecimalFormat5touchER10UErrorCode
    0x181dda37c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : _ZN3icu
13DecimalFormatC1ERKNS_13UnicodeStringEPNS_20DecimalFormatSymbolsER11UParseErrorR10UErrorCode
    0x181dd73ec - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib : unum_open
    0x1804a0bf0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __cficu_unum_open
    0x1803e15cc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFNumberFormatterCreate
    0x180da4f8c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : -[NSNumberFormatter _regenerateFormatter]
    0x180da6040 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : -[NSNumberFormatter stringForObjectValue:]
    0x18504ab10 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIKeyboardGetNumbersStringForActiveInputMode
    0x1850a1f70 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIKBMoreKeyStringForActiveInputMode
    0x1850fe1ac - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar updateLocalizedKeysOnKeyplane:]
    0x1850ff540 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar updateLocalizedKeysForKeyplane:updateAllKeyplanes:]
    0x185104588 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setKeyplaneName:]
    0x18510a714 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar setToInitialKeyplane]
    0x18510a5f4 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar showKeyboardWithInputMode:renderConfig:inputTraits:screenTraits:splitTraits:reload:]
    0x1851e7bcc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardImpl finishLayoutChangeWithArguments:]
    0x1851e826c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardImpl updateLayout]
    0x1851db674 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardImpl _setupDelegate:delegateSame:hardwareKeyboardStateChanged:endingInputSessionIdentifier:force:delayEndInputSession:]
    0x1851d95cc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:delayEndInputSession:]
    0x184e06f84 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _reloadInputViewsForKeyWindowSceneResponder:force:fromBecomeFirstResponder:]
    0x184e06190 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _reloadInputViewsForResponder:force:fromBecomeFirstResponder:]
    0x185417cec - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) _reloadInputViewsFromFirstResponder:]
    0x1854129fc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
    0x1858f81c0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder]
    0x18570c4a0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder]
    0x1856d097c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessaryActivatingSelection:]
    0x1856acf08 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextSelectionInteraction _checkForRepeatedTap:gestureLocationOut:]
    0x1856adc9c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextSelectionInteraction _handleMultiTapGesture:]
    0x1853ecf04 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
    0x184e6a168 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UITextMultiTapRecognizer onStateUpdate:]
    0x184f2b560 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:]
    0x184f32f60 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions
    0x184f307e8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions
    0x184f2ff44 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureForActiveEvents]
    0x184f22bd0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate
    0x184f21ecc - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:]
    0x184f21c3c - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:]
    0x185421df8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
    0x1854017c8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
    0x1854849d8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
    0x185487824 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __processEventQueue
    0x185480218 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __eventFetcherSourceCallback
    0x18040ee88 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    0x18040edd0 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSource0
    0x18040e540 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    0x180408c28 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopRun
    0x180408514 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x18ef06ae4 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x1853e8040 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _run]
    0x1853ebcc8 - /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21E213/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x1046c3f14 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib : xamarin_UIApplicationMain
    0x1059cca50 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_icall
    0x1059cb2f0 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : do_icall_wrapper
    0x1059bfd3c - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_interp_exec_method
    0x1059bd910 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x1058d69b4 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x105a91a14 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x105a98ff4 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x10592ac70 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib : mono_jit_exec
    0x104707ad0 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib : xamarin_main
    0x10304eb44 - /Users/andresdeperedagarcia/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/378C2399-2DD8-42BE-A442-CCB3C3D22453/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7018FB80-FE60-4B7B-A645-964554AFE9B1/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.app/tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones : main
    0x103b91544 - Unknown
    0x1035820e0 - Unknown
    0xe4b800000000000 - Unknown

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1046353b0):0x1046353a0  c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 10 29 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  .._..._..)......
0x1046353b0  e3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91 cd e2 ff 
97  ...T.{..........
0x1046353c0  bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6  .....{...._.
.._.
0x1046353d0  70 0a 80 d2 01 10 00 d4 e3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9  p..........T.{..

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:xamarin_UIApplicationMain <0x000b8>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x0006e>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x0015a>
      at tecnovoice.nukua.formaciones.Program:Main <0x0002c>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x0007e>
      at <unknown> <0x00000>
=================================================================
```

I have iOS version 17.4 and I saw a reddit post that said it could be fixe,  but I still have the error.
https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnetMAUI/comments/1bd1cwz/comment/kuzb4pl/

I've seen that people work for them if they downgrade to the previous version.
Is there any way other than by changing the version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is happening because you are using Xcode 15.3 with iOS 17.4 and the accompanying iOS SDK which isn't supported by .NET for iOS (and thus .NET MAUI) at the time being.

For more information see [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20257).

The easiest is probably to downgrade to Xcode 15.2 (which also runs on iOS 17.4). You could use Xcodes (notice the s at the end) to manage multiple Xcode versions side-by-side.

If you really want to use Xcode 15.3 right now you can use it with the iOS 17.2 Simulator or, using the iOS 17.4 Simulator, add the following piece of code to your `AppDelegate.cs` in the `FinishedLaunching` ([described here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/98941)):

```cs
var date = NSDate.Now;
var locale = NSLocale.SystemLocale;
var str = date.DescriptionWithLocale (locale);
```